# UltiSnips autoexpansion doesn't work with YouCompleteMe

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ultisnips

I use UltiSnips and YCM, which usually works fine. However, I've noticed an issue for autoexpanded snippets. For example, if I have the snippet

```
snippet beg "begin/end" bA
\begin{$1}
$0
\end{$1}
```

and then type `beg` in my document, then I end up with

```
beg$1}
$0
\end{$1}
```

(Of course, I don't actually see the placeholder `$0` and `$1`, but that's how it functions.)

If I call the same snippet something like `hello`, then nothing bad happens. If I don't autoexpand, everything also works like it's supposed to. But it seems that as soon as the expanded bit includes the snippet trigger word, YCM causes the autoexpansion to break. (I know it's due to YCM since disabling YCM makes everything work fine.)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

(reposted from stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216330/ultisnips-autoexpansion-doesnt-work-with-youcompleteme)

**UPDATE:** I have done some testing and have figured out that calling the error something different doesn't change the results. Instead, it seems that the problem comes from using placeholders (like $1) within curly braces.

Comment: If you are sure it's because of ycm and you can't find anything related to this behavior in the help page you should consider asking the question on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues) the people over there will have a more in-depth understanding of the plugin and maybe will already know about the issue, they'll probably give you a better answer than here.

Comment: @statox Thanks, for some reason I didn't think to check the issue tracker! But it turns out that this is already discussed on the UltiSnips page: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1234.

Comment: If you want you can answer your question explaining that it is a known bug and marking the answer as accepted this way if future reader come with the same problem they'll know it's being worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a [known bug with UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1234)